# Antlr: how to print ctx detail?

Tags: antlr4

I see that ctx is a critical object in Antlr.

Example in Java,

```
@Override
public Value visitNumberAtom(MuParser.NumberAtomContext ctx) {
    return new Value(Double.valueOf(ctx.getText()));
}
```

Example in Python,

```
def visitNumberAtom(self, ctx):
    value = ctx.getText()
    return float(value)
```

I am wondering what other attributes or methods that 'ctx' has; especially the token-specific information.

Ideally I could print out (dump) 'ctx' in a readable format.

I'd like to know whether this is possible in Java, Python, and JS. Or what is the best that I can get?

Thank you

EDIT:

I took suggestions from comments and added a concrete example.

Expr.g4

```
grammar Expr;
prog: expr EOF;
expr:
    expr ('+' | '-') expr
    | INT;
NEWLINE: [\r\n]+ -> skip;
INT: [0-9]+;
```

To generate java file:

```
antlr4 Expr.g4 -visitor -no-listener
```

Added override class, EvalVistor.java, to try different ways of dumping ctx.

```
public class EvalVisitor extends ExprBaseVisitor<Object> {
    @Override
    public Object visitExpr(ExprParser.ExprContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("visitExpr ctx.getText(): " + ctx.getText());
        System.out.println("visitExpr ctx.toString(): " + ctx.toString());
        return visitChildren(ctx);
    }
}
```

Main.java, it called toStringTree().

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExprLexer lexer = new ExprLexer(CharStreams.fromString("5+2-1"));
        ExprParser parser = new ExprParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        ParseTree tree = parser.prog();
        System.out.println("tree: " + tree.toStringTree(parser));
        EvalVisitor visitor = new EvalVisitor();
        visitor.visit(tree);
    }
}
```

compiled and ran the program

```
$ java Main
tree: (prog (expr (expr (expr 5) + (expr 2)) - (expr 1)) <EOF>)
visitExpr ctx.getText(): 5+2-1
visitExpr ctx.toString(): [4]
visitExpr ctx.getText(): 5+2
visitExpr ctx.toString(): [2 4]
visitExpr ctx.getText(): 5
visitExpr ctx.toString(): [2 2 4]
visitExpr ctx.getText(): 2
visitExpr ctx.toString(): [20 2 4]
visitExpr ctx.getText(): 1
visitExpr ctx.toString(): [20 4]
```

You can see toString() and toStringTree() both dumped user-friendly output, but not developer-friendly.

As a developer, I'd like to know which attribute of ctx has which token. For example, how can I fetch the INT token?

Comment: Usually you would use `ctx.toString()` to get a readable description. More informative is it to just check the source code, to see what members a class has (and they come most of the time with some documentation).

Comment: Try [ctx.toStringTree(parser)](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/d5064d2d352cbe52741836cd53d868828de74666/_scripts/templates/Java/Test.java#L206).

Comment: thank you for commenting. I updated the question with a complete example.